# Remove special character from array pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, that contain one column  of string.

df example:

```
number | id
---------------
12     | [12, .AZ, .UI]
------------------------
14     | [CL, .RT, OP.]
```

I want to remove the character `'.'`

I tried using `regexp_replace`:

```
df = df.select("id", F.regexp_replace(F.col("id"), ".").alias("id"))
```

But I think regexp_replace is good solution for string not an array.

How can I remove this character from array ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 2.4 or later you can use you can use a [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("id",F.expr("transform(id,x-> replace(x,'.',''))")).show()
```

---

```
+------+------------+
|number|          id|
+------+------------+
|    12|[12, AZ, UI]|
|    14|[CL, RT, OP]|
+------+------------+
```

Working example:

[image]